# Update first_date and last_date to counting customers per period

Tags: python, django

In my django project, it is possible to show every customer in the application with `CustomerProfile.objects.all()` and find the creation date of a specific customer with

```
In [12]: cust = CustomerProfile.objects.get(pk=100)

In [13]: cust.user.date_joined
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 14, 43, 51, 925548)

In [14]: cust
Out[14]: <CustomerProfile: FistName LastName's customer profile>
```

According to the creation date, I would like to make a listing of how many customers has been created per day, week, month or year. An example of the result could be

```
...
week 28 : [ 09/07/2017 - 15/07/2017 ] - Count : 201 customers
...
```

I probably need a range `start_date` and `end_date` where we will list that kind of information. `start_date` will be the date of the first customer created and the `start_week` created would be the week of this first_date. Obviously, the end_date is the date of the last customer created and `last_week` is the week of this `end_date`.

For instance, if I select `Per week` in the drop-down menu and press `Apply` in the form, I want to send information to my model in such I could code what I explained.

So far I know how to count the number of client in a range of two date:

```
CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__range=["2017-09-03", "2017-09-09"])
```

How could I update dates here in such a way we could get a list between the start_week and the end_week? Is there exist an efficient algorithm (with good code performance) to find the `first_date` and `last_date`? A full answer would be appreciate, if possible.

Comment: how about using `timedelta()`? sounds similiar with this [demo](https://python.web.id/trending/) and this [source](https://github.com/agusmakmun/Django-Blog-Python-Learning/blob/master/blog/views.py#L289-L331)

Comment: All my date are of the form datetime.datetime(...). It should be hard to refactor all the code. Why don't you write a full answer? ;)

Answer (score 1):

> to find the `first_date` and `last_date` you can using `.first()` and `.last()` object.

```
first_date = User.objects.first().date_joined
last_date  = User.objects.last().date_joined

customers = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__range=[first_date, last_date])
return customers.count()
```

Comment: I understand your point, but it is not exactly my question, but I like your answer.

Comment: I want the number of customer per period of time (e.g., per week), then the first range is start_date=first_date and end_date=first_date + 7 days

Comment: @SancaKembang, you show try to answer a full answer to that question. It is incomplete so far. You'll get my vote if it is the case.